# Magento 2 Set order status while placing an order

Tags: magento2.3, orders, order-status

In Magento 2.3.x, I want to set the (custom) order status while customer placing an order. How to achieve this using event observer or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="sales_order_place_after">
      <observer name="vendor_sales_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Extensoin\Observer\OrderObserver" />
   </event>
</config>
```

**app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\OrderObserver.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
     public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
     { 
        //Write your code here
     }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Plugin to do the same.

```
public function afterPlace(OrderObject $subject, $result)
{
    $result->setHoldBeforeState($result->getState());
    $result->setHoldBeforeStatus($result->getStatus());
    $result->setState(OrderObject::STATE_HOLDED)
               ->setStatus($subject->getConfig()
               ->getStateDefaultStatus(OrderObject::STATE_HOLDED));

    return $result;
}
```

and di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order">
        <plugin name="order_flow_place_order_plugin"
                type="Company\OrderFlow\Plugin\Model\Order"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

I hope it will help you to get some basic idea.